# window.open(url) method reloads the page again & agan

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem , I need a function/program when  specific screen  reaches it relod
the other window but when I open the window it reloads again & again. I am using window.open()
method to open other link but if you know other better solution I am ready to discuss.

```
function redirect() {
    let deviceWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

    if ((deviceWidth > 320) && (deviceWidth < 720 )) {
        mobile();
    }

    else if ((deviceWidth > 721) && (deviceWidth < 1199)) {

        tablet();
    }

    else if (deviceWidth > 1200)  {

        desktop();
    }
    else {
        console.log("something wrong");
    }






    function mobile() {
        // window.location.replace("./mobile.html");
        let win = window.open('./mobile.html',"_self","",true)
            win.focus();
            
            console.log('mobile');
        
    }
    function tablet() {
        // window.location.replace("./tablet.html");
        let win = window.open('tablet.html',"_self","",true)
            win.focus()
            
            console.log('tablet');
        
    }
    function desktop() {
        // window.location.replace("./index.html");
        

        let win = window.open('index.html',"_self","",true)
        win.focus();
        console.log('desktop');

        
    }
}
redirect();
```

Comment: Add an  `if` in your responsive functions to check the `window.location.href` and if you're already on the page you're trying to load dont call `window.open`.

Comment: It works , The problem was that I was calling the functions even if it is in the same window which causes it recurseive.  Thanks a lot. God bless you.

Comment: Since you provided an answer you should show the full solution so others will get the same help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. The problem was that I was calling the function to open a new html file even if my window is already opened that html file which causes it reapition.
for example: If currently I am in the mobile.html then I was making a mistake by calling it even though it is open.

```
windown.opein("mobile.html")
```

which causes it recursive.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to check if these functions also exist on the page that is being loaded over and over. If so, delete your call to redirect() in the mobile, tablet, and index.html pages. This would cause redirect() to be called recursively.

If you **need** to keep the redirect() function in place, you're more than likely going to need to factor in some if statements. For instance, you can grab the referrer header once you've redirected, and if it's from any of those pages, you can break the loop.